# What do you call someone who holds other people to rules they don't believe in themselves?

Tags: meaning

Title.
This is a very mundanely used word, but I forgot it, and it has been bugging me for a while now and it just won't come back. Maybe someone can help me out quickly. I feel stupid for even asking.

Comment: [hypocrite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrite)? _a person who acts in contradiction to his or her stated beliefs or feelings_

Comment: Yeah, "hypocrite" is the normal term.

Comment: I would say, tyrants.

Comment: (And next time you need a word in such circumstances, don't post a question but instead use a ... uh ... brontosaurus.  (No, that's not it ... what is the word?))